# Where does this Linq statement get the selected value from?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I tried to use the following Linq-Statement:

```
private static void Test(object instance)
{
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)    
    var pis = from pi in
                  (from propertyInfo
                      in propertyInfos
                  select new {
                      PropertyInfo = propertyInfo,
                      Attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Attribute))
                  })
              where pi.Attribute != null
              select pi;
    // End of test method
}
```

I thought there must be an easier way to do this.
However, the Reflector tells me that this statement simplifies to:

```
private static void Test(object instance)
{
    var pis = from propertyInfo in instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        let Attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Attribute))
        where Attribute != null
        select pi;
   // End of reflector output
}
```

and now I wonder where `pi` comes from...

**Edit**

If I add the following lines to the original code:

```
foreach (var item in pis)
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Attribute.ToString() + " " + item.PropertyInfo.Name);
```

they appear unchanged in the reflected code. It seems like `pi` is indeed of the `new { PropertyInfo, Attribute }` type even though an instance is never created. Therefore, selecting `propertyInfo` is not possible.

Comment: please provide the full code instead of `[...]`

Comment: Can you post the actual code and actual result of reflector?

Comment: your second (refactored) code does not compile.you need `select propertyInfo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever Reflector you're using appears to have a bug. <strike>`pi` should be `propertyInfo`. But it's right in saying that your query can be simplified that way.</strike>

Your query can be simplified like so:

```
var pis = from propertyInfo in instance.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    let attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Attribute))
    where attribute != null
    select new {propertyInfo, attribute};
```

Comment: I think this would yield the wrong type as I need both the `propertyInfo` and the `Attribute`.